# How to change date format using jquery in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to  change date format using jquery 
when user select date then text box contain date  as yy/mm/dd format
I was write some code hear

```
<script src="content/dist/js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="content/dist/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id$=txtDate]").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});
    });
</script>
```

aspx code :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Date" TabIndex="7" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What is the problem ? you stuck in which area ?

Comment: problem is date picker open in textbox but  still date formate not change . date formate is still dd/mm/yy    what to do  plz help     can  i  forget some requier file??

Comment: and  i use   <script src="content/dist/js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="content/dist/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id$=txtDate]").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});
    });
</script>

Comment: The above code is perfactly working in my pc @jayesh dhameliya.it's showing 'yy/mmdd' format

Comment: I know above code is perfect   but  it's not  working my  current project and I   will create new project and use this code then it's working perfect  I don't understand what's problem

Comment: Check inspect element in your browser..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the format in c#. Use this code :

```
txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: but i want  selected date not current date

Comment: Update your question to show all of your code. This can make us understand what you want.